# Remove sub-string from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column with entries in the format xxxx200_xx or in some instances xxx200_x.

Is it possible to remove the 200_ and the subsequent characters so that the remaining string is the 4, 5 or 6 digits before the 200_?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` like so:

```
SELECT LEFT(yourColumn, CHARINDEX('200_',yourColumn)-1);
```

So this:

```
SELECT LEFT('xxx200_xx', CHARINDEX('200_','xxx200_xx')-1);
```

Outputs this:

```
'xxx'
```